# Prompting for a variable not working when trying to find random number

Tags: javascript

My assignment for Intro to Javascript is to: "Write a function that accepts two numbers and returns a random number between the two values." It seems easy enough until I attempt to prompt the variables to input, at which point the output seems incorrect.

This is code that is most recommended for finding a random number between two ints, in this case 1 and 6:

```
function getRandomizer(bottom, top) {
  return function() {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1 + top - bottom ) ) + bottom;
  }
}

var rolldie = getRandomizer(1, 6);

document.write(rolldie());
```

The output I get is what it should be, a random integer between 1 and 6. However my assignment is to prompt for the numbers, which can be anything. So I do this, using 10 and 1 as example numbers:

```
var max = prompt("input 10");
var min = prompt("input 1");

function getRandomizer(bottom, top) {
  return function() {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1 + top - bottom ) ) + bottom;
  }
}

var rolldie = getRandomizer(min, max);
document.write(rolldie());
```

The output: 961. Second try: 231. etc. If I set the variables max and min directly to 10 and 1, the code works perfectly, returning numbers between 1 and 10. But for some reason, prompting input and then entering the exact same numbers gives completely different output. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where you have `1 + top` you are adding a number and a string, so the `+` operator will concatenate the values, same with `+ bottom`. Convert the values to numbers, e.g. `1 + Number(top)`, etc.

Comment: `var max = Number(prompt("input 10")); var min = Number(prompt("input 1"));`

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is that the prompts are being treated as strings. So you're actually getting numbers between 1101 and 1.

You can ensure the vars `min` and `max` are numbers by using `parseInt`:

```
var max = parseInt(prompt("input 10"));
```

Comment: If *top* is `'10'` and *bottom* is `'1'`, then `1 + top - bottom` will be `109`, since the `-` operator implicitly converts strings to numbers. ;-)

Comment: You are correct, but then it adds the bottom again, so it will be 1091.

Comment: I was commenting on the result of the expression I quoted. The final '1' is added after the previous result has been multiplied by *Math.random()*, which less than 1 and is floored so the maximum value returned by the function will be '1081' (which is `108 + '1'`). ;-)

Comment: thank you so much! Im kind of embarrassed at such a newbie error because I have used parseInt in the past. But I guess I finally understand what it is and when to use it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code below:

```
var max = Number(prompt("input 10"));
var min = Number(prompt("input 1"));
```